# Subscript out of range on VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing my first VBA. I have a sheet named `Sheet1`. That sheet has a column `E`; I would like to delete all rows which have an empty field on column `E`.

Therefore, I wrote this code:

```
Sub EmptyCells()
   Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("E:E").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

However, when I run it, I get this error:

> Subscript out of range

Why is this error occurring? I am sure the column `E` exists in `Sheet1`. Are my references incorrect?

**EDIT**

If I try `Columns("E")` or `Range("E:E")`, instead of `Columns("E:E")` I get the same error

Comment: it should be `Columns("E")` or `Columns(5)` or `Range("E:E")`, so just a typo.

Comment: You don't have a sheet named "Sheet1".

Comment: @Peh -  "E:E" is quite ok.

Comment: I tried those as well and they don't work. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Vityata huh my bad :( Never seen this. I was sure this won't work. My apologize.

Comment: @Peh - yup, the different type of parameters in general can make different functions. This is called "function overloading", which is allowed in VBA only by the editor. E.g., you cannot define `Foo(k as string)` and `Foo(k as int)`, but the editor obviously can do it with his own functions.

Comment: @Vityata thanks I know that some functions use function overloading, but `E:E` was not obvious to me for the columns function (I would never use that syntax). VBA is very sloppy sometimes it would be better a bit more strict. But I think we're getting off-topic from here.

Comment: If you click on the sheet in the Project Window, you can see its Name and its CodeName in the Properties Window. In the Properties WIndow, the Name is labeled (Name), and the CodeName is labeled Name. If you want to refer to ths sheet directly in your program, you need the CodeName (labeled as Name in the Properties WIndow) : `CODENAME_OF_STHE_SHEET.Columns("E:E")`. Most people use the Name, (labeled (Name) in the Properties WIndow - for instance like `Sheets("NAME_OF_THE_SHEET").Columns("E:E")`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work if there are any REAL empty cells in column **E** (*within UsedRange*).

You may have cells that contain formulas returning *Null*.  `SpecialCells` does not consider them empty.  You may have cells in column **E** containing *Null* as a constant; `SpecialCells` also considers them filled.

**EDIT#1:**

Based upon your specific error message **make sure the worksheet name is spelled correctly**.  `Sheet1` is not the same as `Sheet 1`

Comment: So how can I remove rows containing those cells?

Comment: @octavian  Use a loop *(from bottom to top)* to look for `LEN()=0` and remove those rows.

Comment: Wouldn't you get a "no cells were found" error instead?

Comment: Just occurred to me that you wouldn't get a subscript error if there were no blank cells.

Comment: @SJR  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and it works:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TetsMe()
    MsgBox (Worksheets(1).Parent.Name & VbCrLf & Worksheets(1).Name)
    Worksheets(1).Columns("E:E").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

The different syntax as the index may refer to a different sheet. In this case `Worksheets(1)` is the first worksheet in the workbook.

The `MsgBox()` will tell you which worksheet and which workbook you are changing. Once you know, what you are doing, you may remove it.

If the problem is in the workbook name, then it is easy to change it like this:

```
With Workbooks("NameYourWorkbook").Worksheets("NameYourWorksheet")
    .Columns("E:E").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Comment: This did not fail with an error. However, it had no effect on the Excel data. Are the changes made by this not permanent?

Comment: @octavian - take a look again and try with the `MsgBox()`. It will tell you which `Worksheet()` and `Workbook()` you are changing.

Comment: The line you added fails with `Syntax error`. I don't know how to see a longer error message.

Comment: @octavian - try again, I missed a dot.

Comment: So that prints `my-document-name.xlsx` and `Sheet0`.

Comment: Cool. The easiest way to do something is to change `Worksheets(1)` to `Workbooks("nameofyourworkbook").Worksheets("Sheet-Name-OfYourWorksheet")`, @octavian

Answer (score 1):

Your code works if you have a sheet named/titled `Sheet1`.

```
Sub EmptyCells()
   Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("E:E").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Note that there are different ways to call a sheet.

```
Sheets("Sheet1") 'means the visible name of the sheet is `Sheet1` (not the same as VBA name)
                 'the number doesn't tell anything about it's position, it's just a name.

Sheet1           'means the VBA name of the sheet.
                 'the number doesn't tell anything about it's position, it's just a name.

Worksheets(1)    'means the first worksheet (which ever is in the first position)

Sheets(1)        'means the first sheet (can also be a chart not only a worksheet)
                 'this has no relation to its name which could be "Sheet5"
                 '(If "Sheet5" is in first position).
```